# How to redirect users based on browser language

Tags: php, javascript, internationalization, content-negotiation

1. I want to redirect users based on browser language, I figured out how to do this here, it works fine, here is the code(PHP):

   ```
   if(preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
       header("location:index.php");
   else
       header("location:http://cn.gearor.com");
   ```
2. The problem is I only want to redirect users from other websites or at the first visit to my website. Which means I don't want users reading some pages of my website, when they go back to index, they were redirect to other page. And I also have a link in my website, like: English or Chinese, when users click English from a Chinese page, they will go to index.php and been redirect back to Chinese page, it makes users can't visit the English page. How do I fix this in PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 6):

You can set a session variable like $_SESSION['lang'] and only apply the above code if $_SESSION['lang'] is not set.
what I mean is:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
  if(preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    header("location:index.php");
  }else{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'other';
    header("location:http://cn.gearor.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sinan, this is what I am looking for. But when I put your code into my website, I got an error of unexpected '{' in header.php in line 1. I am using Wordpress, I put the code in the very beginning of my theme before the "<!DOCTYPE html ...". Do I miss anything?

Comment: @Zack Are you sure you want to do this for every single page and post in your worpdress site? If so, put it in the index.php instead. Inside <?php ?> tags, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Well it was hard to understant what you are saying, if you can reclarifiy a bit, but here is what I think you were asking for, [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/psc0ACer).