# unexpected '{' in header.php on line 1 of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am using following code to redirect users based on browser language:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
  if(preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    header("location:index.php");
  }else{
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'other';
    header("location:http://cn.gearor.com");
  }
}
```

I put the code in my WordPress theme, at the very beginning before DOCTYPE, and I got an error: unexpected '{' in header.php on line 1. I can't figure out what causes this.

Related: [How to redirect users based on browser language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352205/how-to-redirect-users-based-on-browser-language)

Answer (score 2):

Can you please supply the code of your header.php? Your post does not tell us where to find line 1 of your code.

Wordpress encourages developers to use the function wp_redirect() for redirecting to other resources instead of sending header() like you would do in php.

For usage see:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Related:
http://wordpressapi.com/solved-header-function-issue-wordpress

Comment: +1 for showing how to stay inside the framework and even linking to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: I just try to use wp_redirect instead of header, but I can open the page because of too many redirection. Here is my header:

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
 if (preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';  
  wp_redirect("http://gearor.com");
 } else  {  
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'Other';  
  wp_redirect("http://cn.gearor.com");
 }
}